# What's the best way of typing the following 58 equations into LaTeX?

Tags: macros, equations, loops, datatool

For an applied math setting, I need to write multiple inequality constraints into a LaTeX report which are all in the form

> x_{i} + x_{j} \ge 1.

I've typed up what "i" and "j" are in an excel sheet as parallel columns. I was wondering if there would be a way to loop through these values to generate the 58 equations, which would save a lot of typing (and it would also really make this scalable if we needed 500 equations, for instance)?

For example:
[image]

Comment: See the datatool package, you will find that you want ! (https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool)

Comment: @flav Thank you!! Could you please give a small example on how I might implement this package?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424659/datatool-loses-the-first-space-in-a-row

Comment: Other people have answered the technical question of "how to do it".

I will suggest a different idea:  don't do it.

Instead, say $x_{i} + x_{j} \geq 1$ for all pairs $(i,j)$ in...  if I saw what you wanted in a book I'd think the author was trying to pad the page length.

Comment: @nomen Thanks for the comment. Yes indeed, it would be a good idea to avoid it, but my purpose is to provide a self-contained report for a integer programming problem, and I'd prefer if the reader need not look elsewhere to get all the details required. I've managed to fit it on one page as a reference table of sorts,

But thanks for the suggestion! I will keep something like that in mind for future reports.

Comment: If you're willing to use a text file (like CSV) instead of Excel, you could fairly easily use LuaTeX to do this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation; the delimiters can be changed.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multicol}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\constraints}{omO{x}}
 {
  \IfValueTF{#1}{\begin{multicols}{#1}\centering}{\begin{center}}
  \egreg_costraints:nn { #2 } { #3 }
  \IfValueTF{#1}{\end{multicols}}{\end{center}}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__egreg_constraints_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_costraints:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__egreg_constraints_seq { \\ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__egreg_constraints_seq
   {
    \__egreg_constraints_item:nn { ##1 } { #2 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_constraints_item:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 }
   {
    $#2\sb{\clist_item:nn { #1 } { 1 }} + #2\sb{\clist_item:nn { #1 } { 2 }}\ge1$ \\
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\constraints{
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6
}

\constraints{
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6
}[y]

\constraints[3]{
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6 \\
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6 \\
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6 \\
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6 \\
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6 \\
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6 \\
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6 \\
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6 \\
  1,2 \\ 3,4 \\ 5,6 \\
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

You can automate the job by exporting the Excel spreadsheet to a comma delimited file (for example `subscripts.csv`) and reading your data with the [`readarray`](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/readarray/readarray.pdf) package.

#### MWE

Assuming that the content of `subscripts.csv` is:

```
1,2
1,3
2,39
7,5
26,5
```

The following code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{readarray}
\usepackage{forloop}

\newcommand\constraint[2]{$x_{#1} + x_{#2} \ge 1$}

\begin{document}

\readarraysepchar{,}
\readdef{subscripts.csv}{\MyMacro}
\readarray\MyMacro\MyData[-,\ncols]

\newcounter{MyCounter}
\forloop{MyCounter}{1}{\value{MyCounter} < \MyDataROWS}
{
  \constraint{\MyData[\theMyCounter,1]}{\MyData[\theMyCounter,2]}\par
}

\end{document}
```

renders:

[image: output]

Answer (score 12):

**Use Excel's `CONCAT` function**.

It's probably easiest to do this in Excel, especially if it's a one-time thing.  Excel has several text-manipulation functions, and I have often found it a very convenient way to generate several similar lines of text or code.  `CONCAT(text1,text2,...)` concatenates a bunch of text and data values into one text output.

If columns **A** and **B** contain your *i* and *j* values, enter the following in cell **C1**:

```
=CONCAT("x_{", A1, "} + x{", B1, "} \ge 1.")
```

and hit Enter.  You can then copy-paste the function all the way down column **C** and get the result you want.  You can then select all the output cells in column **C** and paste into your text editor.

[image]

Comment: concat can also be written using "&", so that the above is equivalent to `="x_{"&A1&"}+x_{"&B1&"}\ge 1."`  Whether this is simpler depends on the code involved.

Comment: Effectively: Q: "How do I use a hammer to plant a screw?" A: "Use a screwdriver"

Comment: Funny thing is I haven't used LaTeX in years, but I did know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found the simplest way to do loops of this sort is the `/foreach` construct in PGF (`\usepackage{pgffor}`). The simplest way to use it would be something like:

```
\foreach \i/\j in {1/2, 1/3, 2/39} {$x_{\i} + x_{\j} \ge 1$ \quad}
```

which would just put everything on one line with `\quad`s between them.

If you want to format this, you might want to line up the greater-thans, e.g. in an align environment. Unfortunately, just doing a `\foreach` loop in an align breaks as it can't handle the `\\` line breaks properly. Instead, we can use a `\foreach` loop to build up a macro, and then afterwards wrap that macro in the align environment. Below (example 2) I use `\xappto` from the etoolbox package to build up the `\constraintlist` macro in this way.

By building things up in a macro, we can get quite creative. In example 3, I'm using the `pgfmath` library to only add `\\` to the macro after every third constraint (otherwise `&` is added), which gives us the constraints in three columns, all nicely aligned on the greater-than sign.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}     % \foreach
\usepackage{amsmath}    % align* environment
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % \xappto and \gappto
\usepackage{pgfmath}    % \pgfmathparse and \pgfmathresult

\begin{document}

Example 1:
\begin{center}
    \foreach \i/\j in {
        1/2,
        1/3,
        2/39,
        2019/2020
    }{$x_{\i} + x_{\j} \ge 1$ \\}
\end{center}

Example 2:
\def\constraintlist{}
\foreach \i/\j in {1/2, 1/3, 2/39, 2019/2020}{
    \xappto\constraintlist{x_{\i} + x_{\j} &\ge 1 \noexpand\\}
}
\begin{align*}
    \constraintlist
\end{align*}

Example 3:
\def\constraintlist{}
\foreach \i/\j [count = \index] in {1/2, 1/3, 2/39, 2019/2020, a/b, foo/bar}{
    \xappto\constraintlist{x_{\i} + x_{\j} &\ge 1}

    \pgfmathparse{mod(\index, 3)==0}
    \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
        \gappto\constraintlist{\\}
    \else
        \gappto\constraintlist{&}
    \fi
}
\begin{align*}
    \constraintlist
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

which renders:
[image: latex render]